# Magento - Change store base url programatically

Tags: magento

I want to programmatically change the base URL (secure and unsecure) for a magento store.

The settings can be changed manually in the backend, seen in the following picture:

http://geo.magenting.com/m/kb/images/attachments/change-magento-base-url_1.jpg

I want to change the values at 4 & 5 for each of my stores.

Something like this:

```
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId);
$store -> setBaseUrlSecure("xyz.com");
$store -> save();
```

Any help on how I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is best done in a data setup script (not a "normal" setup script); see [`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::setConfigData()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L892).

In the setup script, loop through the stores and set the data as follows:

```
/*
    ...
    @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
*/
$stores = Mage::app()->getStores();
foreach ($stores as $storeId => $store) {
    $installer->setConfigData('web/unsecure/base_url',$value,'stores',$storeId);
    $installer->setConfigData('web/secure/base_url',$sValue,'stores',$storeId);
}

/* ... */
```

Obviously it's up to you to determine how to inject the URLs for each correct store.

Answer (score 1):

I know one way is to update the data directly in your database, but there might be better ways to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data where path like 'web/unsecure/base_url' or path like 'web/secure/base_url';
```

The `scope_id` is the `store_id` when the scope is "stores". You can just update or insert the values there.

Answer (score 0):

for production environment you could write in the database at the path `'web/unsecure/base_url'` and at the path `'web/secure/base_url'` simply `{{base_url}}`.

So Magento take the actual Url you are on for the base url.